# Call SignalR method from another assemblies

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, .net-assembly, signalr-hub, signalr-2

Let's say I have 3 projects a **WebApp** , a **Notification** project and a **Business** project. Both WebApp and Business projects can reference Notification assembly which contains SignalR(v2) classes. Suppose I have the following class in Notification project :

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
  public static void SendMessageFromServer(string username,string message)
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

When I use the ChatHub class in WebApp project it works fine, but what I need is to use it in a shared assembly (Notification) to call methods (like SendMessageFromServer) from other assemblies such as my Business project.

Note: other questions that have been answered in Stackoverflow were too old.

Comment: As I understand you want to call hub methods from another application, right? If so https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client .

Comment: No. Just another assembly and suddenly worked by itself !